# Should be split the tag "motivation"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

At the moment [motivation](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motivation) is used in (at least) two rather different ways.

1. For questions on motivations for some mathemtical subjects and related things, like [For calculus students, what should be the intuition or motivation behind series?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1245/for-calculus-students-what-should-be-the-intuition-or-motivation-behind-series)
2. For questions on motivating or motivated individuals like [How to deal with very motivated students having "off-topic" interests?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/90/how-to-deal-with-very-motivated-students-having-off-topic-interests) or [Quotations of Great Mathematicians as a Source of Inspiration for Young Students](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/699/quotations-of-great-mathematicians-as-a-source-of-inspiration-for-young-students)

Both usages are rather common and legitimate, but then in my mind these are rather quite different types of questions. Thus, I am thinking about splitting that tag.

Is this a good idea? If so, how could the new tags be named?  (Preferrably the name should make the intended usecase clear, but since we have tag wikis it is not crucial.)

Comment: I think "motivation" should apply to case 1. I don't have a good suggestion for what to tag case 2 questions, but I agree they should be different.

Comment: Aha, there is a "gifted-students" tag. That covers one of your examples of case 2.

Comment: @brendansullivan07 an option could be to use some existing tags like the one you mentioned and to tag the rest with a [to be introduced general-pedagogy  I proposed](http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/281/143)

Comment: (There is still no concept-motivation tag...)

Comment: What is a good method to split the tags? Is there a way to do it without bringing all related questions to the top?

Comment: @MarkusKlein There is no actual method for this. The only thing moderators can do is rename and merge tags. So the best one can do is retag manually all but  "one part" (the largest). This remainder then can be renamed.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman I agree we should have that tag. (Its creation did just not happen in the process of retagging). If you think it fits somewhere, please add it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update (quid): I did the rename discussed in comments. So all [motivation](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motivation) is gone :-) There might be room for finer tuning, but I think the [student-motivation](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/student-motivation) sort of fits for all that remaons and the rename does not *prevent* any later optimsation.

---

I think, we agreed on introducing [concept-motivation](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/concept-motivation) for questions of the first type and [student-motivation](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/student-motivation) for questions of the second type? (And maybe as soon as there will be more question, to introduce another tag like [teacher-motivation](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teacher-motivation) or whatever comes next.

I would split the following questions which are now tagged as [motivation](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motivation) as follows. Please comment if you don't agree. (Stroked questions are already re-tagged)

**concept-motivation [concept-motivation](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/concept-motivation)**

- <s>[What are some good ways to motivate and introduce reasoning abstractly about abstract algebra?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/228/what-are-some-good-ways-to-motivate-and-introduce-reasoning-abstractly-about-abs)</s>
- <s>[What are some good mathematical applications to present in an abstract algebra course?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/269/what-are-some-good-mathematical-applications-to-present-in-an-abstract-algebra-c)</s>
- <s>[What are some good motivating questions for introductory abstract algebra?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/403/what-are-some-good-motivating-questions-for-introductory-abstract-algebra) (duplicate!)</s>
- <s>[How can you explain the importance of $e$ to those who have not taken calculus?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/425/how-can-you-explain-the-importance-of-e-to-those-who-have-not-taken-calculus)</s>
- <s>[Is $e^{i\pi}+1=0$ a good motivation for introducing $e$ or $i$? Why (not)?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/444/is-ei-pi1-0-a-good-motivation-for-introducing-e-or-i-why-not)</s>
- <s>[What is a good motivation/showcase for a student for the study of eigenvalues?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/520/what-is-a-good-motivation-showcase-for-a-student-for-the-study-of-eigenvalues)</s>
- <s>[For calculus students, what should be the intuition or motivation behind series?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1245/for-calculus-students-what-should-be-the-intuition-or-motivation-behind-series)</s>
- <s>[How to motivate equivalence classes](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1447/how-to-motivate-equivalence-classes)</s>
- <s>[Counterintuitive consequences of standard definitions](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1538/counterintuitive-consequences-of-standard-definitions)</s>
- <s>[What are easy examples from daily life of constrained optimization?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1545/what-are-easy-examples-from-daily-life-of-contrainted-optimization)</s>

**student-motivation [student-motivation](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/student-motivation)**

- <s>[How to deal with very motivated students having "off-topic" interests?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/90/how-to-deal-with-very-motivated-students-having-off-topic-interests)</s>
- <s>[Examples why university education is important for future high school teachers](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/130/examples-why-university-education-is-important-for-future-high-school-teachers)</s>
- [What arguments can I give a high school student why mathematics is important?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/150/what-arguments-can-i-give-a-high-school-student-why-mathematics-is-important)
- [How can we help students who are very anxious about math?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/194/how-can-we-help-students-who-are-very-anxious-about-math)
- [Use of mathematical humor suitable for motivation/explaination?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/553/use-of-mathematical-humor-suitable-for-motivation-explaination)
- [How to encourage women to study mathematics?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/584/how-to-encourage-women-to-study-mathematics)
- [Can math movies help us in teaching?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/597/can-math-movies-help-us-in-teaching)
- [How to create and support a mathematics club or group that will last?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/598/how-to-create-and-support-a-mathematics-club-or-group-that-will-last)
- [Motivating student by showing them where we are heading to](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/667/motivating-student-by-showing-them-where-we-are-heading-to)
- [Quotations of Great Mathematicians as a Source of Inspiration for Young Students](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/699/quotations-of-great-mathematicians-as-a-source-of-inspiration-for-young-students)
- [How does an advisor effectively motivate progress on an independent project?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/829/how-does-an-advisor-effectively-motivate-progress-on-an-independent-project)
- [What are some activities/projects I can assign to calculus students from bio/chem/physics majors to specifically motivate their interest?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1164/what-are-some-activities-projects-i-can-assign-to-calculus-students-from-bio-che)
- <s>[Students who have succeeded before but are not succeeding now](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/students-who-have-succeeded-before-but-are-not-succeeding-now)</s>

**Not sure**

- [What is fairly new theorem one can teach (and prove) to an undergraduate student?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/686/what-is-fairly-new-theorem-one-can-teach-and-prove-to-an-undergraduate-student)
- [Making standards for "showing work" explicitly clear to students](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/714/making-standards-for-showing-work-explicitly-clear-to-students)
- [Examples of Research Level Math Discoveries Done by Undergraduate Students](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/779/examples-of-research-level-math-discoveries-done-by-undergraduate-students)
- [Examples of Good Mathematical Games for a Mathematical Olympic](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/780/examples-of-good-mathematical-games-for-a-mathematical-olympic)
- [How does one create "good" math problems?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1380/how-does-one-create-good-math-problems) (retagged [problem-design](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem-design))
- [What is gratifying in being a mathematics teacher?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1498/what-is-gratifying-in-being-a-mathematics-teacher) (that would maybe be a good question of [teacher-motivation](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teacher-motivation)?)

Comment: Excellent work here. I think the math club one is definitely student-motivation, while the "showing work" question doesn't actually get any of these tags.

Comment: I retagged a couple of them but don't want to totally drown out the new question queue with the retags... is there any way to retag without causing this disruption?

Comment: @ChrisCunningham As quid mentioned in the comments of the question: **There is no actual method for this. The only thing moderators can do is rename and merge tags. So the best one can do is retag manually all but "one part" (the largest). This remainder then can be renamed** -- I suggest to just retag the ones for concept-motivation and others and let him (or another mod) retag the student-motivation questions.

Comment: Thanks for doing all the retagging work. I did one more manual retag; and changed motivation to student-motivation. I also agree with the one where you suggest teacher-motivation; but that question having been edited a lot recently I thought I will not do this just now. Yet, also it has a student-motivation aspect; actually I think it might be the teachers tag that might be repalced by  the teacher-motivation, and we might do so when untangling the teachers tag.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who deals with primary and secondary students, the second meaning is more familiar. Perhaps we should avoid the motivation tag completely, and find other tags fo each of these meanings.

Comment: This is a good point. What would you think of calling one students-motivation and the other mathematical-motivations? (It can be useful to have word for which people might search when chosing a tag in the name as tag search matches strings)

Comment: @quid I seem to have sneaked in a similar suggestion 11 seconds before your comment!

Comment: @BenjaminDickman Yes, I just noticed and was in the process of commenting on yours. But again you were faster than me! :-) I think your suggestion is better.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

> teacher-motivation, student-motivation, concept-motivation

For (repetitive) clarity: The first refers to questions about motivating teachers; the second refers to questions about motivating students; and the third refers to questions about motivating concepts.

It's true that the word *motivation* is not being used the same way in the first two vs. the third; however, I think that the difference is clarified by these lengthened versions (and accompanying descriptions).

Comment: (More or less reposting my comment from elsewhere.) I like this suggestion. It seems people use the word 'motivation' intuitively in both ways. Thus it is good to have the word actually in the tag in all cases, as tag search matches strings. I think these three should cover the usecases nicely and concept-motivation seems a better name for what I called mathematical-motivation. I think the risk of confusion will be small, already just from the names, and having a brief tagwiki it can be avoided altogether.

Comment: I like [tag:student-motivation] and [tag:concept-motivation], but [tag:teacher-motivation] is unclear to me. Can you maybe provide 1-2 examples for this?

Comment: @MarkusKlein, not sure it will come up here, but all the horrid VAM ("value-added meausures") stuff, where they want to pay teachers more who allegedly raise test scores more, relates to this. I think they have a wrong conception of teacher motivation.

Comment: Perhaps we don't need the teacher-motivation tag until the issue comes up, if ever.